# initiate a phone call on android with special character #

Tags: android, phone-call

I use the following code to launch a call from within the android app:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+12345 #123"));
startActivity(intent);
```

While it starts the call, it ignores everything starting with the #.

I read something about modifying SpecialCharSequenceMgr.java file, but I can't find this anywhere and quite honestly don't know what exactly one has to do. What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the problem is the that the # symbol has a special meaning in URIs, so you have to encode it using the `Uri.encode()` method like this:

```
    Intent out = new Intent();
    out.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("+12345#123")));
    startActivity(out);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This causes the telephone screen to open and show the correct number (including the special character) but it doesn't start the call anymore. One has to press the green phone button manually. Is there a way so that the call gets initiated without manually pressing the button? Many thanks...

Comment: Sure, you just have to use the ACTION_CALL action instead of ACTION_DIAL, and to use that you need the android.permission.CALL_PHONE permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that Jon is not completely right on your question, the idea was not so bad, though...
You need to use special character map to initiate pound key:

```
Intent intcall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:5555" + "%23"+"additional number"));
startActivity(intcall);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent out = new Intent();

out.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("+12345#123")));

startActivity(out);

Answer (score 0):

just do this.it worked for me.

```
Uri.parse(Uri.encode("your string value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

i found this and it works fine for me > unity 2020.3

'Application.OpenURL( "tel://Number" );'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).