# Initiate a call to a number with special characters (,)

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to start a call from a Phonegap application on an Android phone running 2.2. However, it is ignoring any pause characters I insert into the number. For example, if I insert a pause character as 'p' or as '%2C', they are ignored and don't appear in the dialer.  If I use ',' for the pause, the number appears truncated at the point the comma appears, i.e. "12p34" becomes "1234" and "12,34" becomes "12".

Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

Edit: This appears to only effect some versions of android. When tested on some other devices, the special characters appeared as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this question/answer: [initiate a phone call on android with special character #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815785/initiate-a-phone-call-on-android-with-special-character)

This might not be a phonegap issue at all.