# how to launch dialer using phone number with special character (pound #)

Tags: android

I want to launch android dialer using phone number with pound character in it. I don't want to make direct call but rather open the dialer and let the user to call(this way, I don't have to request permission in the app to make calls). Is this possible?

I tried the following but after launch the dialer, there was no number shown.

```
View poundTaxi = this.findViewById( R.id.pound_taxi_big_button );
    poundTaxi.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
    {    
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v ) 
        {
            //Get the number from the URL
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:#8294"));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: yes. what have you tried, what failed ?

Comment: hi @njzk2, I just edited my post, and shows what I tried. Could you help?

Comment: oh, actualy, I found this that solved the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815785/initiate-a-phone-call-on-android-with-special-character

Answer (score 1):

To dial please try like this:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("#8294")));
startActivity(callIntent);
```