# Intent.ACTION_DIAL with number ending with #

Tags: android, android-intent

So I'm trying to send a number via `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` ending with # i.e for example `*123#`. But when the Android Dialer app is started, there is only `*123` (# is missing).
I'm using following code to trigger the Dial Application of Android.

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:*124#");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Anticipated Thanks!! 
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer could be related with this link 
[initiate a phone call on android with special character #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815785/initiate-a-phone-call-on-android-with-special-character) 

This line could be the key
`Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode("*124#"));`

Answer (score 5):

You need to properly encode the hash tag (#). In your URL requests it should be %23, so replacing it with %23 will do the trick.

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:*124%23");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

You can also let URI do the encoding:

```
String encodedPhoneNumber = String.format("tel:%s", Uri.encode("*1234#"));
Uri number = Uri.parse(encodedPhoneNumber);
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Accepted the answer of @anj0 as it is more realistic.