# ACTION_CALL Intent getting rid of # at the end of number

Tags: android, android-permissions

The below code makes calls within android however, the # at the end of the number is removed and the android calls the number without it, is there a way to specify that android should keep the # at the end of the number cause I need it in this case?

```
Intent startCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:*001203#");
startCall.setData(uri);
startActivity(startCall);
```

Android Manifest has the below permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent.ACTION\_DIAL with number ending with #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702918/intent-action-dial-with-number-ending-with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this snippet on clicking :

```
call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String s = Uri.encode("*001203#");
            Intent callIntent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);;
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+s));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String hash = Uri.encode("#");
String ussd = "*" + hash + "001203" + hash;
startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)), 1);
```

this is the workaround.