# Make a phone call to number containing "#"

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a phone call to a number containing "#" and "*". My problem is 
the "#" didn't write in the number that I'm trying to call.

Example : A phone call to "*142#" , it just shows a phone call "*142".

I'm using :

```
Intent i = new Intent()
        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
        .setData(Uri.parse("tel:*142#"));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", Uri.encode(number)))
```

Comment: I can't use it ! , Why?

Comment: I need a little more information. What do you mean you can't use it?

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815785/initiate-a-phone-call-on-android-with-special-character

Comment: look , http://up.harajgulf.com/do.php?img=898992

Comment: Thanks <3 , It helps.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is because # is a special character for URI's. In order to get around this you need to encode it using URI.encode. Take a look and try the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent()
           .setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
           .setData(URI.parse("tel:" + URI.encode("*142#"));
startActivity(i);
```