# when i am using call intent automatically remove # from number

Tags: android, android-intent

```
String num= "*345*20#";
Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);  
callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+num));   
startActivity(callintent);
```

In the above code when I use number with a '#' the '#' is removed automatically from the number. How can I fix it?

please help me. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815785/initiate-a-phone-call-on-android-with-special-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below:

```
String num= "*345*20#";
Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);  
callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode(num)));   
startActivity(callintent);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a URI with special characters like `#`, which is a **reserved character**. In order to use those characters in your URI, you have to encode the URI content like so:

```
String num= "*345*20#";
Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);  
callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(num)));   
startActivity(callintent);
```

The `encode()` method will percent-encode the URI.
See here for more info:

[Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

[W3Schools Url Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)